# как залочить xml на время работы тулзы на JAVA

Tags: java, файлы

Есть xml, который открываю для редактирования на java.

Как сделать так, чтобы на время работы тулзы, редактировать файл никто другой не мог?

Дополнение: Нужно учесть, что тулза может быть завершена аварийно, поэтому `file.setWritable(false)` наверное не подойдет (файл останется залоченым)

К сожалению, вариант

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    file.setWritable(true);
}));
```

Не подходит, потому что если, во время работы программы, аварийно ее завершить, файл остается read only.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Как это аварийно? его кто то интерраптит или он падает от нехватки памяти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setWritable` вполне подходят для ваших целей. А чтобы файл не оставался залоченым после остановки приложения, может помочь вот это

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        file.setWritable(true);
    }));
```

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать  1. что должно быть вместо стрелочки в записи new Thread(() -> {            2. Эту конструкцию нужно вызывать из статического метода или возможно из обычного?

Comment: Это называется lamba function,попробуйте, вам понравится. Если же вы пишите на java версии 1.7 и ниже, то можете написать так, new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                file.setWritable(true);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JavaApplication17 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final File file = new File("myFile");

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
           file.setWritable(true);
        }
    });

    try {
        file.setWritable(false);
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // обработка исключений
    } finally {
        file.setWritable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант работает.

Comment: Увы, не всегда тот код который работает, является корректным и правильным.

Comment: Опишите, в чём пример некорректен и неправилен, пожалуйста. Чтобы не повторять ошибок.

Comment: Ок. mainThread.join() зачем? это абсолютно безполезная конструкция, т.к. main поток уже умер после того как shutdownhooks начинают выполняться. Плюс простынка из catch это не красиво, тем более что в них одно и тоже

Comment: По поводу простынки - допустим. Косметика.  mainThread.join() - в данном случае не нужен. (Как и вывод абсолютного пути и запись в файл необязательна.)

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, как Вы оцениваете текущую версию примера, очищенную от лишних операций?

Comment: На мой взгляд неплохо)

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо. Но, если запускать код из среды разработки, и останавливать выполнение(например при дебаге), то блок finally не отработает? Если не отработает, то файл(допустим это важный xml) останется доступным только для чтения навсегда

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, в вопросе, что Вам нужно отлавливать три ситуации (а не две) - аварийное завершение, обработка Ctrl+C и отлов ситуации с использованием точки останова. Штатно - ситуация простоя должна обвязываться: сделайте синглтон-читалку, к которой обращались бы другие приложения, если важна доступность. И пусть этот синглтон хранит очередь транзакций, вносит единолично правки в файл и оповещает об изменениях состояния документа.