# FileLock не лочит текстовый файл

Tags: java, файлы

Не работает FileLock.
Кодом лочу текстовый файл. Открываю Nodepad++, вношу изменения и вижу, что у меня остались права на доступ. Что нужно исправить в коде, чтобы на время работы тулзы, никто кроме текущего потока не мог изменить содержимое файла?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Learn\\SomeLessons\\src\\data.txt");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    FileLock lock = outputStream.getChannel().lock();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    lock.release();
}
```

Comment: И сохранить получается?

Comment: Да, получается сохранить.

Comment: Ситуация оказалась немного сложнее, после выполнения lock.release, содержимое файла полностью стирается вдобавок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обратиться к [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) по `FileLock`, то можно прочитать, что фактическая реализация лока зависит от системы: может использоваться как обязательный, так и необязательный лок. Также там рекомендуется не уповать на обязательность лока, а рассматривать его как необязательный, потому как его обязательность не может быть гарантирована.

> Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing
>   the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore
>   unspecified. [...] To ensure consistent and correct behavior across
>   platforms, it is strongly recommended that the locks provided by this
>   API be used as if they were advisory locks.

На [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) тип лока зависит от того, какой именно API используется.

> For applications that use the file read/write APIs in Windows,
>   byte-range locks are enforced (also referred to as mandatory locks) by
>   the file systems that execute within Windows. For applications that
>   use the file mapping APIs in Windows, byte-range locks are not
>   enforced (also referred to as advisory locks.)

Если файл был залочен необязательным локом, это означает, что другие процессы не будут иметь доступ к файлу только если они будут проверять наличие лока (например, тоже пытаться залочить файл). При этом если другой процесс не проверяет наличие лока, он по-прежнему имеет полный доступ к такому файлу.

По-видимому, именно с таким сценарием вы и столкнулись. Можете попробовать пооткрывать файл в других приложениях, чтобы убедиться, что часть из них откажется работать с файлом.

По поводу того, как исправить: код, приведенный в другом вашем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556800/), не решает проблему?

Comment: да, в связанном вопросе все разрешилось, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Для этих целей можно попробовать изменить доступ к файлу, например вот так:

```
file.setWritable(false);
```

Как ответил уже @andreycha `FileLock` сильно зависит от платформы и порой работает не так как хочется.

Можно пойти дальше и настроить более гибко, для владельца файла, его группы пользователей и всем остальным.

```
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<>();
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), perms);
```